# Number of substrings possible with even characters

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Consider a string 'ABBAA'
Possible substrings with even number of characters are 4
'ABBA' : Count of 'A' is even and 'B' is even
'AA' : Count of 'A' is even and 'B' is even ($0$)
Similarly 'BB' and 'BBAA'.
So a total of $4$ substrings are possible.

If given string is 'AABCCBBCAA'
substrings possible are "AA" "BB" "AA" "CC" "BCCB" "CCBB" "CBBC" "CBBCAA" "AABCCB"

So total $9$ substrings

Is there any pattern or sequence or algorithm to find this?

Comment: It looks like the total count would depend highly on the way the given string is formed. That is, only if one restricted [in various ways] how the original string must be built could one get such total formulas. Then they would apply to some families of such given strings.

Comment: Order seems to matter, but your first example counts only $4$ valid results. I could see the empty string, $AA$, $BB$ and the permutations of $AABB$ (which is $\binom{4}{2,2}$ = 6$), for a total of $9$ valid configurations.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri How is for example the permutation ABAB of AABB obtained as a *substring* of ABBAA ?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri ignore empty strings and substrings must be contiguous

Comment: @coffeemath any kind of algorithm is ok, no exact formula is needed